# Reading from, and then replacing all the text in a .txt file

Tags: python, text, twitter

I'm very new to Python (and coding in general, if I'm honest) and decided to learn by dipping into the Twitter API to make a weird Twitterbot that scrambles the words in a tweet and reposts them, _ebooks style.

Anyway, the way I have it currently set up, it pulls the latest tweet and then compares it to a .txt file with the previous tweet. If the tweet and the .txt file match (i.e., not a new tweet), it does nothing. If they don't, it replaces the .txt file with the current tweet, then scrambles and posts it. I feel like there's got to be a better way to do this than what I'm doing. Here's the relevant code:

```
words = hank[0]['text']
target = open("hank.txt", "r")
if words == "STOP":
    print "Sam says stop :'("
    return
else:
    if words == target.read():
        print "Nothing New."
    else:
        target.close()
        target = open("hank.txt", "w")
        target.write(words)
        target.close()
```

Obviously, opening as 'r' just to check it against the tweet, closing, and re-opening as 'w' is not very efficient. However, if I open as 'w+' it deletes all the contents of the file when I read it, and if I open it as 'r+', it adds the new tweet either to the beginning or the end of the file (dependent on where I set the pointer, obviously). I am 100% sure I am missing something TOTALLY obvious, but after hours of googling and dredging through Python documentation, I haven't found anything simpler. Any help would be more than welcome haha. :)

Comment: So let me brief your Q by removing the story. You want to read as will as edit a file by opening a single instance of the file. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`with open(filename, "r+") as f:
    data = f.read()// Redaing the data
    //any comparison of tweets etc..
    f.truncate()//here basically it clears the file.
    f.seek(0)// setting the pointer
    f.write("most recent tweet")// writing to the file`

No need to close the file instance, it automatically closes.
Just read python docs on these methods used for a more clear picture.

Comment: i will as soon as i am allowed haha

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `yield` to compare hank.txt and words line by line so that more memory space could be saved, if you are so focused on efficiency.
As for file operation, I don't think there is a better way in overwriting a file. If you are using Linux, maybe 'cat > hank.txt' could be faster. Just a guess.